# What is deleted when I delete a Business Unit?

Tags: marketing-cloud, admin, sfmc-business-unit

We're just putting BU on our account.
I saw we can delete it whenever we want, we just have to be sure all users are removed from the BU (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_delete_a_business_unit.htm&type=5).
Silly question but... if I click on "Delete" in the Business Unit menu, what will be deleted ? I can't find any article about this.

I imagine all Emails, Data Extensions, Cloud Pages are deleted if they are not in a shared folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything would be deleted in that child business unit including assets such as data extensions, emails in Content Builder, CloudPages, and SMS messages.

Also settings such as Sender Profiles, Reply Mail Management, Sender Authentication Package, Installed Packages, and connector settings (if multi-org setup).

Your subscribers would roll up to your parent account so those technically wouldn’t get “deleted.”

I would make absolutely sure you want to delete the child business unit before doing so.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it's very clear !